# Finding a grammar is not LL(1) without using classical methods and transforming it to LL(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, compiler-theory

Let's say i have this grammar:

```
S -> A C x | u B A
A -> z A y | S u | ε
B -> C x | y B u
C -> B w B | w A
```

This grammar is obviously not LL(1), which i can find constructing the parsing table. But is there any way i can prove that this grammar is not LL(1) without using the classical methods i.e. without constructing the parsing table or finding any conflicts?

Also how can i convert this grammar to LL(1)? I think i have to use both epsilon-derivation elimination and left recursion elimination but its a bit tricky and as many times i've tried i couldn't transform it to LL(1).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It can be seen directly that the grammar is not LL(1) by the fact that you can reach S from itself by going S(first alternative)->A(second alternative)->S, with no tokens consumed in between. That would cause infinite recursion in a recursive descent parser. I'll leave the transformation to LL(1) for someone like @rici - I could probably do it (if it's possible), but it's not routine for me (either).

Answer (score 2):

Both `S`/`A` and `B`/`C` involve [indirect left-recursion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Indirect_left_recursion).

Since no left-recursive grammar (direct or indirect) is LL(k) for any *k*, you can prove the grammar is not LL(1) simply by showing the left-recursive cycle. (On the other hand, if you have a tool which computes FIRST and FOLLOW sets, the "classical" method is really very simple.)

Eliminating indirect left recursion involves first finding one possible topological sort of the non-terminals and then breaking the derivation cycle by substituting some uses of a non-terminal with its right-hand side. After that, the simple left recursion elimination algorithm can be applied.

You can find concrete examples of this transformation [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999916/step-by-step-elimination-of-this-indirect-left-recursion), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085501/elimination-of-indirect-left-recursion), or in any good textbook on parsing theory. (Or, of course, by searching for the term "indirect left recursion" and looking for pages with some credibility.)